# How can I add an additional line break (paragraph return) to each line break found in an Open Office Document?

Tags: find-and-replace, openoffice-writer

I have tons of text that runs together paragraph breaks like so:

```
off the wounded, and with the same calmness and composure as before resumed the watch over his armor. 
But these freaks of his guest were not much to the liking of the landlord, so he determined to cut matters short and confer
```

...whereas it should be:

```
off the wounded, and with the same calmness and composure as before resumed the watch over his armor. 

But these freaks of his guest were not much to the liking of the landlord, so he determined to cut matters short and confer
```

I got a tip on this from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/691419/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-superfluous-line-breaks-in-an-open-office-document), which pointed to [this mini-article](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/replace-line-breaks-openoffice-44956.html)

Based on the info there, I tried replacing "$" with "$$", and although it found the invisible "$"s, it replaced them with visible (literal) double "$"s. I then tried replacing "$" (with the "Regular Expressions" checkbox ticked) with "#13#10" but that also simply inserted that literal string there.

How can I auto-replace all line breaks / paragraph marks with two of the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your example right, you just want to add a newline after every line, right?

In OpenOffice 3.2.0 Writer

- Search for: `$`
- Replace with: `\n\n`

[image] [image]

OpenOffice [regular expression reference](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Writer#The_.27Replace_with.27_box_.5Ct_.5Cn_.26_.241_.242)

Comment: Thanks; I'm about to leave, but I'll czech it out when I get home.